# How to make div and input tags to stay selected after user clicks

Tags: html, css, forms, input, label

I have quiz script that i want to design it, so when user clicks on the div/input tags it will stay selected with another background color.

All i succeeded to do is when i click on the div i can see that the div background has changed,
and also, when i click on the input i can see text background color is changing and stay selected.
But as i said, i want it to stay selected.

I also have a problem that when i click on the div, the input dont select.
Only if i click on the input- only then i can see it is selected.

Here's the code:

```css
.quest {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.quest:hover {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ddffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.quest:active {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fef9a5;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.rd {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rd:checked+label {
  background-color: #fef9a5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="quest">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="rd" />
    <label><span class="rd">test</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I think you must add an id for input, then for attribute to the label similar to the id name of input. Then style the label to occupy the space of its wrapper.

Check this code below if this answers your problem:

```css
.quest {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.quest:hover {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ddffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.quest:active {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fef9a5;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.rd {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 3px 30px 0;
}

.rd:checked + label {
  background-color: #fef9a5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="quest">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="rd" id="test"/>
    <label for="test"><span class="rd">test</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well I'm glad it helped you :), consider this as an answer then?

Comment: You got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a pseudo element on the label to simulate your background. The trick is to make it relative to the div element and not the label:

```css
.quest {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.quest:hover {
  background-color: #ddffff;
}

.rd {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.rd:checked+label {
  background-color: #fef9a5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rd:checked+label:before,
.quest:active label:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background-color: #fef9a5;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="quest">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="rd" />
    <label><span class="rd">test</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is working when i only click on the input itsef. I want to achive that when i click on the div to stay selected.